# Testing react controlled input with cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

I'm use ant desing like component library and cypress for testing

I have this input and want to test it:

```
<Input
  data-cy="methodology-input"
  value={fileName}
  onChange={(e) => setFileName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

But then I use `cy.type()` it not typed. I find the solution, but I think it bad:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=methodology-input]').then((input) => {
  const nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value').set;
  const inputDOM = input[0];
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(inputDOM, 'test');
  inputDOM.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
});
```

How can I test it without bad code?

Comment: How about you do this - `cy.get('[data-cy=methodology-input]').click().type('Some text').type('{enter}')` ?

Comment: It works ok with a clean react app + antd + useState for fileName. What else do you have in the component? Any useEffect?

Comment: I think it harder to understanding than it can will be